# What is the most efficient approach for bidirectional data streaming through BLE?

Tags: stream, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an app which will be acting as a BLE central (scanning for peripherals), running on iOS 8 and above. Also I have a custom accessory acting as a peripheral (advertises a custom service with custom characteristics).

I intend to be sending about 20KB of data in bursts, about 10 times per hour back and forth between the central and the peripheral.

Naive approach seems to have two characteristics on the peripheral:

- read and notify
- write

When the peripheral wants to send data to the central, it will send notification for the first characteristic and then the central will request the value of the first characteristic.

When the central wants to send data to the peripheral, it will just write to the second characteristic.

It seems, characteristic indications are of no use and also I can write without waiting for responses (the peripheral will let me know about errors and ask to resend the data).

But I'm not sure if I'm not missing something.

**Are there any better ways to stream ~20KB data through BLE as fast as possible?**

**Are there any show-stoppers why this approach would not work at all in CoreBluetooth acting as a central?**

*Not dealing with MTU and characteristic sizes - I have created another SO question for those; for the sake of this question just assume that they are as large as practically possible.*

Comment: "When the peripheral wants to send data to the central, it will send notification for the first characteristic and then the central will request the value of the first characteristic." Why don't you simply send a lot of notifications, one for each chunk of data?

Comment: I guess I don't know BLE spec good enough yet - I thought that sending large amounts of data through notifications is not good practice and it is better to use long (a.k.a. blob) reads. But if sending chunks through notifications is more efficient than notify+blob read, then I'll try it.

Comment: Notify+multiple read blob requests are very inefficient. Read blob requests uses basically two round trips per MTU-1 number of bytes since there may only be one outstanding request at a time, and the peripheral usually has not have enough time to respond in the same connection event. With notifications the link layer will send multiple notifications in the same connection event.

Comment: However note that implementations are allowed to drop notifications if they run out of buffer space etc. Same with Write Without Response. Android does not drop anything but I'm not sure about iOS.